# running external program and feeding its outputs as inputs to variables

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

In the following code, rval3 is hardcoded and I do some manipulation to get
the rev. Which does what I expect.

```
    int rval3= 0x0c10; // want to make this generic
    int rval3= *buf;
    int rev;
    rev = (rval3 >>10) & 0x7;
    printf("rval3 = %X\n", rval3);
    printf("rev = %x\n", rev);
```

*Output*

```
rval3 = C10
rev = 3
```

I have modified the original code, so that the value that is fed to rval3 is not hardcoded, but taken from another device and my results changes to a value which I am expecting. The intermediate value buf is correct. But when I try to feed it to rval3, I might be doing something wrong. Can someone correct me where I am going wrong.

```
    char *cmd = "/opt/phytool read ps0e0/0xEF/3";
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fp;
       if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening pipe!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        // Do whatever you want here...
        printf("OUTPUT: %s", buf); // OUTPUT: 0x0c10
    }

    if (pclose(fp)) {
        printf("Command not found or exited with error status\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //int rval3= 0x0c10; // want to make this generic
    int rval3= *buf; // buf holds 0x0c10
    int rev;
    rev = (rval3 >>10) & 0x7;
    printf("rval3 = %X\n", rval3);
    printf("rev = %x\n", rev);
```

Below is the output, which doesn't match with the Original output before modification.

*Current Output*

```
rval3 = 30
rev = 0
```

Comment: `int rval3= *buf` Nope. `*buf` is a `char`. On a typical computer made after 1980, `char` is 8 bit. `rval3` cannot possibly be `0x0c10`, that doesn't fin in 8 bit.

Comment: `0x0c10` is not the same as `"0x0c10"`. If `buf` holds the string `"0x0c10"`, then `*buf` (which is essentially the same as `buf[0]`) has the value `'0'` which is the same as `48` or `0x30`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I can see the issue now. So should I process the input as a string, remove the `0x` by manipulating the string and proceed along. Or is there a neater way to do this? I am from HW background and relatively new to SW programming, apologies it is a naive question.